# rsync --delete did not remove file in destination while with ssh

Tags: centos, ssh, rhel, rsync

On my RHEL6 pair of servers, I tested the rsync from server-1 to Server-2 with SSH.  Everything was good as expected. However, when I moved a file under A directory, A/x.file to B/ of /home/user on Server-1, repeated the same rsync with --delete (or similar options) did not remove x.file on A/ and backup  x.file to B/ on Server-2.  Here is the rsync script:

```
rsync -avhu -e ssh --delete home/user/ remote_user@remote_host:/home/user/.
```

ssh was set up without passphrase.  I tried different order of those options, none of them work, meaning that x.file was still under A/ at destination (server-2), not on B/.  What went wrong?

Comment: Can you include the first few lines of the log output from rsync? It occasionally skips deletion if anything was amiss with the transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some general guidance on how to get rsync to do what you'd like it to do using the options you've selected in your script:

To copy the contents of a directory from the *source* directory to a remote *destination* directory (the first time), you can do:

```
    rsync --archive --verbose --human-readable source -e ssh username@servername:/home/user/ .
```

Once you've made some changes to the *source* directory that you'd like to sync with your *destination* directory, do:

```
    rsync --archive --verbose --human-readable --delete source/ -e ssh username@servername:/home/user/source .
```

Take note:

- When you first copy a source directory to a destination directory, you *do not* need to follow source with a / (forward slash).
- When you *sync* a source directory to a destination directory, you *do* need to follow source with a / (forward slash).This / means the content of the source directory, and *not* the directory itself.

You can test drive your script with this option: 
        --dry-run .

Comment: Isn't the `destination` missing in the first command?

Comment: The omission is intentional @sebix. In this case, rsync will create a directory called _source_ in `/home/user` on the remote server.

Comment: Okay, but you wrote `to a remote *destination* directory`. Now you say `source = destination`.

Comment: That's a fair point @sebix, and one I overlooked. I'll amend my initial proposal accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This slightly modified code works for me:

```
rsync -avhu -e ssh --delete /home/user/ remote_user@remote_host:/home/user/.
```

If your production code really does reference `home/user/` instead of `/home/user/` then that could easily be a reason it's failing. You would also be getting an error `rsync: change_dir "/home/user//home/user" failed: No such file or directory (2)`